# How do you implement bower in AWS Lambda?

Tags: bower, aws-lambda

*Total noob here.* 
**How do you implement bower in AWS Lambda?** I'm trying to have AWS Lambda run `bower install` but I'm not sure how to upload bower into AWS lambda. I have tried googling for tutorials and pre built lambda functions and I have not found anything related to bower.

Answer (score 1):

You have to deploy the package to either S3 or Lambda with all the dependencies packaged together. You cannot install dependencies from Lambda itself. Here is a link that might help if you want to deploy from your machine to Lambda using npm: https://medium.com/@SlyFireFox/micro-services-with-aws-lambda-and-api-gateway-part-1-f11aaaa5bdef#.6bk44snwm.

Comment: Unfortunately Bower needs disk access, and I've so far been unsuccessful in telling it to use /tmp